# First tab to be selected by default

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuex

I have a vuejs/vuetify application that has tab bars using v-tabs/v-tab components to navigate between pages. Fortunately, when clicking a tab, gets the current data but what i need is when entering to the application, a tab should be open or selected by default.
Here is the tab component:

```
<v-tabs  v-model="tab">
  <v-tab  v-for="file in selectedFiles" :currentTab="currentTab" :key="file.name"  @drop="onDrop($event, file)" @click="onTabSelect(file)">{{ file.name }}
  </v-tab>
  <v-spacer/>
</v-tabs>
```

and the reference of FileTabs :

```
   export default {       
      name: 'FileTabs',
      data () {
        return {
          tab: false
        }
      },
      props: {
        selectedFile: null,
        selectedFiles: null
      },
      mounted () {
        this.tab = this.calcFileIndex()
      },
      watch: {
        selectedFile () {
          this.tab = this.calcFileIndex()
        }
      },
      methods: {
        onTabSelect (file) {
          this.$emit('select', file)
        },
        deleteTableRow: function (idx) {
          return this.selectedFiles.splice(idx, 1)
        },
        calcFileIndex () {
          if (this.selectedFile === 1) {
            return this.tab
          }
          const idx = this.selectedFiles.findIndex(({ name }) => name === this.selectedFile.name)
          if (idx < 0) {
            return this.tab
          }
          return idx
        }
      }
    }
```

**I need first tab to be selected by default.**
Can someone please tell me how i can do it or to suggest me how to do it?

Thank you in advance and enjoy the day :)

Comment: set the default value at ```data(){return {tab:defaultTab}}```

Comment: @DanielaC.Montenegro  thank you for answering, i appreciate it.
I tried to set  ' tab: defaultTab '  but it is not working. Should i declare the 'defaultTab' somewhere or how this works? Sorry, i am new in vuejs

Comment: how are you declaring the tabs list?

Comment: @DanielaC.Montenegro the tab i am calling from another component like this:  
` <FileTabs :selectedFiles="selectedFiles" :selectedFile="selectedFile" v-on:select="updateSelectedFile" v-if="selectedFiles.length > 0"/>  `




**where the data is:**



`
data () {
    return {    
      selectedFile: {
        code: null
      },
      selectedFiles: []
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.selectedFiles = []
  },
`

Comment: ok, so you're setting the tab index with the selectedFile?

Comment: @DanielaC.Montenegro yes

Comment: I see... what does ```data(){return {tab:1}}``` return?

Comment: @DanielaC.Montenegro It turns the tabs but only when i click it which is supposed to be clicked by default the first tab

Comment: remove ```mounted () {this.tab = this.calcFileIndex() }``` from your code, then try.

Comment: @DanielaC.Montenegro i tried and its the same :/

Comment: The problem lies at ```calcFileIndex ()```, since you are setting the value of the tab to something that hasn't been set. Try changing ```if (this.selectedFile === 1)return 1;```

Comment: also, change the return to ```this.selectedFiles.findIndex(({ name }) => name === this.selectedFile.name)```, since you're returning an index, then at your watcher put the validation that if the ```index<1```, then ```this.tab=1```

Comment: Can you please put a {{tab}} to see the value assigned by v-tabs when you click one tab? I think v-model is a simple array index starting at 0 and you can't use your own keys.

Comment: I mean that to select first tab, you only have to set tab=0. But you are using this.calcFileIndex() on mounted to set the initial tab value. Is this call returning a 0?

Comment: @Txema I set the tab to 0 and it is the same, it is not making any difference if i put tab=1 or 0 or null where it shows the same output. Yes the call is returning a 0 means where return nothing, return no tab.
Even if i change to 1, return no tab.

Comment: I don't know, it should be as easy as initialize tab to zero: https://jsfiddle.net/txemavs/76k9o5p2/

Answer (score 0):

Change the logic behind the calculation of the index:

```js
        calcFileIndex () {
          return this.selectedFile === 1    
                         ?    1
                         :    this.selectedFiles.findIndex(({ name }) => name === this.selectedFile.name);
        }
```

Then in your watcher, validate the index:

```js
        selectedFile () {
          let index = this.calcFileIndex()
          if(index>0) 
              this.tab = index;
          else 
              this.tab = 1;
        }
```

Also, set the props better, if it is numeric, then put the type as numeric and validate that it is greater than zero:

```js
props:{
    selectedFile:{
       type:Number,
       default:1,
       validator:function(value){return value>0;}
    }
}
```

You can check more types at the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation), to avoid weird errors.

Comment: the first tab index is not zero?

Comment: I'm not the code owner, you might as well ask in the question comments. I did this considering an id from a database rather than an index from a list.

Comment: @DanielaC.Montenegro I changed the code as you wrote but is showing the same as before was. Its not being selected the first tab by default. Strangely not working..

Comment: Open Vue Devtools and capture the ```tab``` value, for us to see it.